# Stop a list animation on hover

Tags: jquery

We have done the animation here :

[Animation list](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeosing/x9MU4/1)

```
function run() {
    //jQuery("li").click(function() {
    var prev = jQuery("#rotated li:first-child");
    jQuery.unique(prev).each(function (i) {
        jQuery(this).delay(i * 600).slideUp(function () {
            jQuery(this).appendTo(this.parentNode).slideDown();
        });
    });
    //});
    jQuery('#rotated li:first-child').hover(function () {
        jQuery(this).pause(true,true).slideUp
    })
}
window.setInterval(run, 3000);
```

We only need to stop the animation when the user hover the element "#rotated".

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use clearInterval()

```
var intVal = window.setInterval(run,3000);

$('#rotated').on('mouseenter',function(){
clearInterval(intVal);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/x9MU4/2/)

If you want it to continue rotating when mouseleave do this

```
$('#rotated').on('mouseenter', function () {
    clearInterval(intVal);
}).on('mouseleave', function () {
    intVal = window.setInterval(run, 3000);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/x9MU4/3/)